# How to "follow" symlink in Ranger to open containing directory of target?

Tags: ranger

In Ranger, I often have symlink and I want to go to the containing directory of the file that is linked to. How to do this with Ranger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bit hard to find but ranger can do this with the `gL` keymap.

After you type `g` you'll see a list of commands:

```
key          command
 L           cd -r %f
```